# Opening a 12kb text file takes WAY too long....?

Tags: android, sd-card, fileinputstream

The following code works, but takes way too long (over a minute) to open a small file. The LogCat shows a lot of instances of "GC_FOR_MALLOC freed #### objects / ###### bytes in ##ms". Any suggestions?

```
 File dirPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyFolder");
 String content = getFile("test.txt");

 public String getFile(String file){
  String content = "";
  try {
   File dirPathFile = new File(dirPath, file);
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dirPathFile);
   int c;
   while((c = fis.read()) != -1) {
    content += (char)c;
   }
   fis.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   getLog("Error (" + e.toString() + ") with: " + file);
  }
  return content;
 }
```

Update:

This is what it looks like now:

```
File dirPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyFolder");
String content = getFile("test.txt");

public String getFile(String file){
    String content = "";
    File dirPathFile = new File(dirPath, file);
    try {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dirPathFile));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        content = new String(text);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getLog("Error (" + e.toString() + ") with: " + file);
    }
    return content;
}
```

Thank you all!!

Comment: I tried a few different things and now it's a lot faster. I can read a 200kb file in about 5 seconds, so that's an improvement, but I need to open about 5 of these files and 5 seconds each is still a long time, so I'm going to use SQL lite and just query the data instead. I've been programming for a long time, but I'm new to android and Java, so this is more like a learning exercise. Thanks a bunch for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `+=` on a String is **extremely** inefficient - it will constantly allocate and deallocate memory, something you need to avoid!

If you need to constantly add characters, use a `StringBuilder` and give it a sufficiently big buffer up front.

However, it's even better to just read the entire file as a byte array and then create a string from that byte array. Use the `String(byte[])` constructor.

Comment: I know. There should be a mandatory comment when downvoting anything. It's really not helpful otherwise, to anybody.

Comment: I agree, that's definitely something that should be implemented. Would keep away a lot of the people who just downvote because they disagree by opinion, too.

Comment: Seems like the upper management disagrees: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes . Their solution was to add the "you may want to add a comment and explain your downvote" hint.

Comment: Eh, yeah, so I see. :/ They do have some good reasons, though, I can admit.

Comment: I'm now using StringBuilder, but couldn't find a working example for String(byte[]). Thanks a bunch for your answer!

Comment: Ricky - try something along the lines of: `byte[] buffer = new byte[dirPathFile.length()]; br.read(buffer); text = new String(buffer);` (I may have gotten something wrong, but it's kind of like this.)

Comment: I tried messing with that, but I got all kinds of errors. I'm new to android and java, so this is still a little over my head. Right now, the way it is, it works, so I'll leave it like that and revise it later when I get some time. Thanks for your help!! :D

Comment: No problem! You should consider doing it with the read(byte[]), that's a lot faster still. Give it some time, get more comfortable with Java and Android. If you have something that almost works, you could post another question to Stackoverflow too and hopefully we can get you there. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

> content += (char)c;

Well, here's your problem. String concatenation is *slow* if you have to do it repeatedly. And you're reading the file one character at a time, which is also really slow.

You want to be using the `read(byte[] buffer)` method to read the file into a buffer efficiently. And then you can stringify the buffer if need be.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than reading a single byte at a time, you should read multiple using [read(byte[])](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d%29).

Also, Strings are immutable, so every time you do String s = s + "a"; there is the possibility that you are creating a new String object.  You can use [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead to build up a larger string.

Answer (score 2):

[Schlemiel the painter](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) strikes again!

Comment: +1 for the link. I don't have a lot of low-level programming experience, but I always enjoy reading stuff like that!

Answer (score 0):

try to read with buffer [read(byte[] buff)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d%29)

Answer (score 0):

The reasons are:

1. You are creating too many String objects with `content += (char)c;` - use StringBuilder instead to append with read data, then in the end call toString() on the StringBuilder.
2. You don't use a byte[] (or char[], it depends on implementation) buffer to read from file. Usually 1KB buffer is optimal instead of reading one by one byte.